# How to virtualize grid of components using ngx-virtual-scroller

Tags: angular

Here's what I have: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-56pper?file=src%2Findex.html

I want to use ngx-virtual-scroller with a grid of cards.

I created 2 tabs. The first tab should be virtualized but isn't working unless I set a fixed height. The second tab is not virtualized but it is what I'm trying to emulate. I want to use the scroll bar from the `body` element and not the tab content, which is why I need to pass something to the `parentScroller` property.

I wonder if this is possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Usually virtual scroll expects the parent container to be the `parentScroll`, if I set the parent as the parent scroll and do an inspect element and ensure the parent height in coming from the root element, your example is working great!

Also please note that material tabs destroys the content when its not the active tab, so I guess the height of the tab is not propagated for  virtual scroll to do its thing!, we have the property `preserveContent` but that is only available for angular material latest version, where we can preserve the content of the tab without destroying it!

scroller html

```
    <div style="width: 100%; margin: 15px 10px; height:100%;" #test> <!--  changed here -->
      <virtual-scroller
        [enableUnequalChildrenSizes]="true"
        *ngIf="virtualize"
        #scroll
        [items]="data"
        [parentScroll]="test"
      > <!--  changed here -->
        <mat-card
          *ngFor="let i of scroll.viewPortItems"
          style="height: 150px; width: 200px;"
        >
          Item #{{ i }}
        </mat-card>
      </virtual-scroller>
      <div
        *ngIf="!virtualize"
        fxLayout="row wrap"
        fxLayoutAlign="start center"
        style="gap: 10px;"
      > <!--  changed here -->
        <mat-card *ngFor="let i of data" style="height: 150px; width: 200px;">
          Item #{{ i }}
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
```

main html

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div fxFlex="100">
    <div fxLayout="row wrap"
         fxLayoutGap="10">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;"
             fxFlex="25" style="display:contents">
            <child-component>
            </child-component>
            <span *ngIf="items.length !== i + 1 && items.length!== 1">,&nbsp;</span>
            <span *ngIf="items.length === i + 1" style="
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;"> this is a very long sssssss hhhh hhhhhhhhhhh hhh hhhhh hjjh  jhh
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-flex-layout-example-xfae9w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I guess the thing I'm trying to figure out is how we can use the parent's scroll wheel, instead of the tab content.

Comment: Made some progress here https://stackblitz.com/edit/window-virtual-scroll-strategy-x2zf8u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fwindow-vritual-scroll%2Fwindow-virtual-scroll.directive.ts

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose updated my answer, using `flex-wrap` to wrap the text!